# CSS does not work using master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

my CSS has been always worked well. but, when I decided to switch one of my regular web form ( asp.net ) pages to a content page ( using master page) and I connected the right CSS file (the one Iv'e always used) to the master page, just a part of the CSS commands is working since then.
the CSS commands using classes are working but commands with id selector are not working. I really have no idea how to fix it.
what can I do?

a part of my CSS:

{

```
#MainPanel
{
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d3cce3, #e9e4f0);       
}
#NotAvailableTicketsLabel
{
    float:right;
}
#BasketPanel                                                    
{
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #fc4a1a, #f7b733);
    margin-left:513;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

}

this is the code I have been always used, but after what Iv'e done, only the CSS classes is working. That means that only if I will put a point in place of the hashtag, then it would work.

Comment: please supply some code

Comment: You can use chrome developer tool to see if style is overrided or they dont get the style from your css file.

Comment: OK thanks, I looked at it and I think they don't get the style from the CSS file. Also, I noticed that all the element's ID had the phrase "ContentPlaceHolder1_" added to their names (probably because of the master page Iv'e added) . This i can only see with the developer tool and not in visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <pages clientIDMode="Static"></pages>
</system.web>
```

It will keep your original IDs and stop ASP.NET from adding extra markup to them.

Comment: Thank you it worked . But, do you know why it changed the size of the template field in my gridview ?

Comment: Can't tell without seeing the gridview, but probably the css now works and that changed it. Maybe need to adjust the css.